# PowerBi, how to view push data sets raw data

Tags: powerbi

I've created a powerbi push dataset using the api. I can build reports based on this but I'm struggling with something very simple.

How do I see my data?

On the web app I can choose analyze in excel but excel gives me an error

[image: Excel error]

Within the powerbi desktop I cant find an option for this either. Does anyone know where to find this? Could it be a permissions issue? If so where do i find the option to turn this on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a report on a Push dataset, there are no Data and Relationships sections to the left in Power BI Desktop. But you can place a visual (e.g. table), right click it and select "Show Data":

[image]

This will show you the underlying data in tabular format in Power BI Desktop, but if you want, you can export it to file and open it in Excel. Just click the ellipsis in the top right corner and select "Export data":

[image]

You can also connect Excel directly to your Push dataset in Power BI Service. To do this you will need to install [Power BI publisher for Excel](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-dashboard-publisher/) and from "Power BI" tab select "Connect to Data":

[image]